# Do pets receive a sight benefit from their Parents' Oracle's Elixir?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do Champions that make/obtain pets in game gain sight of stealthed champions or Wards vis a vis their pets if they have an Oracle's Elixir?

Champions include:

```
Maokai (seedlings)
Annie (Tibbers)
Malzahar (Voidling)
Yorick (Ghouls)
Mordekaiser (Ghost)
Zyra (Plants, Seedlings)
```

Comment: I'd say no since that would be a very unbalanced feature, but don't have a firm basis for it :/

Comment: If my memories are right, no, you doesn't gain sight of stealthed champ, since you have the oracle buff, but your pets doesn't. Still not sure about Evelyn stealth, which work differently... You need to be at a certain distance of her, so maybe pets show her, but not sure.

Comment: Oracles reveals target at certain range of your champion, which means the pets don't attack until you're in range.

Comment: There is only one situation I can think of that a pet gains vision, and it involves Mordekaiser's clone on a champ with Lightbringer, and I'm not even sure that would work. Shaco + Lightbringer would work, though Vision is still not true sight.

Comment: What is Lightbringer?

Comment: @ccreason The Lightbringer is an item which reveals stealthed traps: _Unique - Trap Detection : Nearby stealthed enemy traps are revealed._ Quoted fom the LoL wiki. It's like an Oracle's except without stealthed champoin detection (and it lasts forever until you sell it).

Comment: It also gives +50 attack damage, +20 armor, +12% life steal, another unique passive and a unique active.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Oracle's Elixir](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Oracle%27s_Elixir): Grants 750 radius stealth detection to **champion** until death.

As you can see the radius is around the champion and has nothing to do with pets.

Note: This item no longer exists in the current game(Patch 3.14).

Comment: Parsing what the words themselves say is not a good method for determining edge cases in LoL. 'Impassable terrain' is often anything but. Gotta test it.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Ingame it just reads something along the lines of "grants detection of stealthed objects until death" or something. This is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

No. Pets do not receive the effects of Oracle's Elixir.